# Duplicate UIViewControllers on UINavigationController stack after application wakes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I just learnt IOS programming and am writing my first iPhone app.

My app provides info on an MKMapView, the view controller of which is the root view controller of a UINavigationController. If the mobile signal is bad  i use mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError: to make the app push one of two different view controllers onto the navigation controller stack depending on what the user is doing. Code follows:

```
    - (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"mapViewDidFailLoadingMap: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [aiView stopAnimating];

        if (mapTypeInt == 0) {
            NSString *message = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your signal is not currently 
     strong enough to download a map. Switching to table view."];
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Maps Unavailable"
                                                         message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [av show];
            if (currentMode == @"retracingSteps")
            {
                RetraceViewController *rvc = 
    [[RetraceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RetraceViewController" bundle:nil];
                [[self navigationController] pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
            }
            else{
                TripTableViewController *ttvc = [[TripTableViewController alloc] init];
                [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ttvc animated:YES];
            }
        }
        else{
            [self setMapType:0];

            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"Your signal is not currently strong enough to download a satellite map. 
    Switching to Standard Map view."];
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't Use Satellite Maps"
                                                         message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [av show];
        }



    }
```

Yesterday I tested the poor mobile signal in a rural valley and the correct second view controller was pushed onto the stack. What I then noticed when I locked the phone and rechecked the app after a few minutes was that on waking, the root view controller was displayed quickly followed by the view controller I expected.  In effect what this did was to push an identical copy of the second view controller onto the stack. I discovered this when I had to tap the back button half a dozen times to get back to the root view controller.

What I would like the app to do on wake up is to immediately display the view controller that was live when the phone is locked rather than the root view controller. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I am not using storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was caused by the handler mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError: being called multiple times before control passed to the pushed view controller. I fixed the bug by making three changes to the handler method:
1) I removed the UIAlertView show and moved it to the pushed view controller;
2) I used a flag (initialized in viewDidAppear:) to return from the handler without executing the push if the handler was being called a second time;
3) I checked for the pushed view controller's existence before allocing it.

When all three of these changes were made, transitions between view controllers happened correctly. Code follows:

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error
```

{
    [aiView stopAnimating];

```
if (mapViewFailed > 0) {
    mapViewFailed ++;
    return;
}

if (mapTypeInt == 0) {
    [map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];
    [self removeAsNoticationsObserver];

    if ([currentMode isEqualToString:@"retracingSteps"])
    {
        if (!rvc) {
            rvc = [[RetraceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RetraceViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        if (!ttvc) {
            ttvc = [[TripTableViewController alloc] init];
        }
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ttvc animated:YES];
    }
    mapViewFailed ++;


}
else{
    [self setMapType:0];

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your signal is not currently strong enough to download a satellite map. Switching to Standard Map view."];
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't Use Satellite Maps"
                                                 message:message
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
}
```

}

No doubt a more elegant solution is available which I don't know about yet, being an iOS newb.

Comment: The code looks fine, however, `==` **SHOULD NOT** be used for string comparison. Use `-isEqualToString:`.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected my code and edited my post to address this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happened because even you lock the screen your app still receiving locations update (location services can run code in a real background mode), also when you push a view controller the previous one in the stack still exist and still receiving location update and doing everything has been designed to do, so even you push another controller, if something happen that for the implemented logic has to push another controller, this view controller has access to the navigation controller so has just to add to the stack another controller and push it (the navigation controller still the same for all the VC in the stack)

So what you have to do is stop to handle this cases when you push another controller and restart to do that when you pop back the controller

Comment: I do need to keep the location controller running while the phone is locked. Are you saying that I need to Pop back the navigation stack  somewhere like applicationDidEnterBackground: in the app delegate?

Comment: If is a location based application it's fine that you keep the location services active in background, I mean that when you push a view controller you should change the logic to dial with the fact that the controller that manage the mapview is not long the current view controller, and so if RetraceViewController has been pushed and the map view fail again will push another RetraceViewController, ot avoid this you can stop the push if the map view controller is not the currect vc, or before do the push pop-back all the pushed view controller and push the one that is correct fot that status

Comment: Since my location controller delegate is a separate object, which sends notifications on change of location, I amended the map view controller to stop receiving notifications before pushing the tripTableViewController. This made no difference. I then tried setting it to nil before creating it which resulted in errors: nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar; Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TripTableViewController: 0x16cab0>; Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted. I am confused!

Comment: I suppose that the pushViewController code is into the locationUpdate notification handler? In this case or you didn't remove properly the observer, or there is somewhere some code that is re subscribing for that notification... Also check if you are subscribing for notifications more than once, remember that for each time you subscribe each time the notification handler will be called...

Comment: I had bought a mac mini to develop iOS apps. This has turned out to be  a false economy as I decided I had to get a mac book and take it with me to the wilderness and create nslogs to test this. It turns out that multiple pushes of the same VC were occurring because mapViewDidFailLoadingMap: gets called multiple times before control passes to the pushed VC. I created a flag to make the method do nothing on subsequent calls, which has fixed it. Next I need to know  why it happens. May be due to the UIAlertView.

Comment: like I suggested you in the previous comment, have you checked how if you are subscribing the notification multiple times? and also have you something like `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` into the notification handler method that push the viewcontroller ?

Comment: yes, notification center subscription only occurs in init. Yes i have added removeObserver:self into the handler method. Like I said, I have discovered the reason for the duplicate push. It was caused by the handler method being called again before control passed to the pushed VC. I went to the wilderness area today, having turned off the uialertview, and no VC duplication occurred. I am almost ready to provide my own answer to this thread that says this. I need to do a bit more testing first.